# excel 2010 import xml with nested elements creating duplicate records

Tags: xml, excel-2010

I have an xml file which imports fine except for one problem. Each record in the xml file has an  element which can contain multiple  elements.

When i import this, excel creates a new record for every . So if i have a record that has 5 images, I'll have 5 rows in the excel table which are all duplicate except for the image column.

I'd like it if excel just added enough columns so that all the images associated with each record were on a single row and I didn't have duplicate records.

Anyone know if this can be done with excel 2010? I can upgrade to excel 2013 if it would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would make any difference.

Excel not being hierarchical (like XML), will interprets your 5 images as 5 different records (with the same ancestors data).

You might be able to do what you want with some XML mapping but I never tried it myself.

You could also write a custom vba function to import the xml as you like.

Comment: Seems rather silly for them not to have some other options - if they are going to support the import of an xml file, which does support hierarchies, i think they could have at least put slightly better handling options. Anyhow, someone else in another forum suggested a an excel macro might be the way to do it. Just not sure how to do that since I've never written any excel macro's before.